# How to put multiple elements inside a class attribute python3

Tags: class, python-3.x, attributes, adventure

I am working on a text adveture. I have a room class, and an item class, but when I put more than one item inside the room, I get problems. 
Here is an example of the code:

```
class Place(object):
"""The Room class"""
    def __init__(self, name, Item):
        self.name = name
        self.Item = Item


class Item():
"""The Item class"""
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


PC = Item("PC")
Bed = Item("Bed")   

bedroom = Place(name = "Bedroom", Item = {PC, Bed})

print (bedroom.Item.name)
```

And the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Documents and Settings\Kenneth\My Documents\Python_Projects\projects\
TA.Project\location\classes2.py", line 18, in <module>
print (bedroom.Item.name)
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'name'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This works when I only have one item, but when I try to add more I get errors.  I tried to create a for loop to show one item at a time, but that didn't work either. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

The loop I tried was something along the lines of:

```
for i in bedroom.Item:
    print (i)
```

Attributeerror 'Place' object has no attribute 'Item'

Answer is accepted, I would like to update the code for anyone else having a similar issue:

```
class Place:
    def __init__(self, name: str, items: set):
        self.name = name
        if items is None:
            items = set()   
        self.items = items

    def get_item_names(self):
    # one-liner: return [x.name for x in self.items]
        names = []
        for item in self.items:
            names.append(item.name)
        return '\n'.join(names)


    def get_item_value(self):
        value = []
        for item in self.items:
            value.append(item.value)
            return value


class Item:
    def __init__(self, name: str, value: iter):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value


Bed=Item("Bed", 200)
Chair=Item("Chair", 10)
Oven=Item("Oven", 500)


bedroom = Place("Bedroom", {Bed, Chair})
kitchen = Place("Kitchen", {Oven})


print (bedroom.get_item_names)
```

The values function was to prove that the Item class was still working.

Comment: Can you show the loop you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reuse class-names as variable-names! This only confuses and leads to errors. :)

For me, it works with `bedroom.Item` without problems, but maybe you swapped some upper-/lowercase letters?!

`AttributeError: 'Place' object has no attribute 'Item'` means your `Place`-class does not provide the variable `Item`. So if you actually named the variable `item` or `Items`, you would have to ask for that and not for `Item`.

---

**Already written before update on question:**

When you use multiple items in one room, you are, instead of having just one particular item, giving `Place` a set of items. So when doing `bedroom.Item.name` you are actually asking the `set`, stored in `bedroom.Items` to give you it's `name` (which it does not provide, therefore the error).

I would recommend a clear definition. Let `Place` always expect multiple items (maybe there is just one, but if it is still in a set, then my suggestion works anyway).

*Example:*

```
class Place:
    def __init__(self, name: str, items: set):
        # The `items: set` notation is only for better understanding.
        # It is valid Python3 syntax, but does not ensure the actual type!
        self.name = name
        if items is None:
            item = set()   # this is to avoid possible erros later.
        self.items = item

    def get_item_names(self):
        # one-liner: return [x.name for x in self.items]
        names = []
        for item in self.items:
            names.append(item.name)
        return names

class Item:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name

bedroom = Place("Bedroom", {Item("Bed"), Item("Chair")})
kitchen = Place("Kitchen", {Item("Oven")})

# usage:
>>> print(bedroom.get_item_names())
["Bed", "Chair"]
>>> print(kitchen.get_item_names())
["Oven"]
```

The main difference is the usage of the loop (in `get_item_names`) to get all those names.
If you want to hold track of the items themself, you still got the `items`-set over which you can iterate:

```
>>> for item in bedroom.items:
...     print(item.name + ":", item)
Bed: <__main__.Item object at 0x7f0c081327f0>
Chair: <__main__.Item obect at 0x7f0c08132898>
```

Comment: This fixes my problem. I thought that by placing "Item" in the Place variables: Class Place(self, name. Item), I was declaring that only Items could fit here. I was experimenting with using a list instead: "RoomInv[], but couldn't get that to work the way I wanted. I did not know what set was, so I don't think I could have figured it out. You are a lifesaver.

Comment: Good to hear, it helped. I would recommend to have another look into Python and Python-Class introductions. Maybe things get easier then (for the future). :)